# Operating Systems: Page table on context switch

Tags: memory, process, operating-system, virtual-memory, page-tables

I have a question: if a context switch occurs, why the page table of the new process has to be reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

The page tables of the new process don't have to be reloaded. They still lie in RAM. I don't think page tables can be swapped to the hard-disk. It means that the page tables remain in RAM and only the CR3 register (**for x86-64**) changes to point to the set of page tables of the new process taking place.

I don't know to what extent operating-systems use the capability of x86-64 processors. I know that, today, x86-64 processors have a tagged TLB. And some page table entries can be set to be "global" with the G bit. The cached translations (in the TLB) are not flushed for global entries on CR3 reload so it saves some overhead on context switch.

Comment: ok, so when a process switch occurs: the TLB is invalidated, the cache also is invalidated and in the MMU are loaded the pointers to the new process page table? The page table of the switched process is not modified?

Comment: I would also have another doubt: when the memory is full: the pages are overwritten or saved in secondary memory because they will be needed later (when the related process will go into execution)?

Comment: Hi, any news???

Comment: I don't have much more info on caching. Maybe ask another question someone else may be willing to help. Maybe cs.stackexchange.com (computer science) would be a better place to ask this kind of general question.